# Word of the Day #2

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Test run, take two. The first run went well, so let's keep it up!

*For your second riddle, things might just get trickier -*
*With some common bond, things might just get stickier!*
*When I'm with a group I'll be holding you tight;*
*When alone, I'll protect you in the absence of light.*

*What am I?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not too sure, but I'll guess:

> Rubber

With some common bond, things might just get stickier!

> Rubber cement (a type of adhesive)

When I'm with a group I'll be holding you tight;

> Rubber band (group = band)

When alone, I'll protect you in the absence of light.

> Rubber (i.e. condom, "protection" at night time, alone = no other word)

Comment: You're just on the same wavelength as me, aren't you? :o The one thing you didn't point out is that cement is the "common bond", but I'm impressed at how quickly you pick up on all of my wordplay!

Comment: @BaileyM Well it took me a while to come up with it.  I kept getting stuck on words like "glue", "guard", and "dark".  Looking forward to the next one.

Answer (score 8):

I think the answer is

> Stick

With some common bond, things might just get stickier!

> Glue Stick

When I'm with a group I'll be holding you tight;

> As in the idiom `stick to`. To Stick to a group

When alone, I'll protect you in the absence of light.

> A stick helps to navigate when its pitch dark.

Comment: For the third clue maybe "Nightstick" fits.  It's another word for a trunceon or baton.

Comment: @JS1: I never knew it had a name :-)

Comment: This is a really good answer! Not what I had in mind, but +1 for sure.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's

> Phosphorus

With some common bond, things might just get stickier!

> Maybe refers to how sugar-phosphates form the backbone of DNA and RNA, helping it "stick" together, or maybe the "sugar" component, making it sticky.

When I'm with a group I'll be holding you tight;

> This could mean like the phospholipids(that have phosphorus) in the cell membrane, which holds it together.  Of course, people are made up of cells.

When alone, I'll protect you in the absence of light.

> Phosphorus is used in the heads of matches, which would help you in the dark.

Not really sure… Just a guess

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that gets into my mind is

> A blanket

With some common bond, things might just get stickier!

> When you sleep together with a person, under the same blanket, that means you two are very close, probably couples.

When I'm with a group I'll be holding you tight;

> Together with other people under a blanket, it sure feels cramped and tight.

When alone, I'll protect you in the absence of light.

> During the night, the blanket protects you from the cold or insects.